# Start-Process fails to start the service

Tags: powershell, start-process

I'm a newbie to powershell. I am working on a script which is not starting the service intermittently.

```
$sensuresult = Start-Process -Wait -FilePath $filepath -ArgumentList '/tasks="assocfiles,modpath" /quiet' -PassThru
```

Basically here we are trying to install a .msi package. Intermittently the above line fails.

```
Write-Host $sensuresult

Write-Host : The following exception occurred while retrieving the string: "Process has exited, so 
the requested information is not available."
At line:8 char:1
+ Write-Host $sensuresult
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Host], ExtendedTypeSystemException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : 
ToStringPSObjectBasicException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteHostCommand
```

With the above error message I really do not know if Start-Process failed or Write-host.

Can I get some insights on why Start-Process is not installing the package intermittently and what is the best alternative way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

you can start process by first check the process is running or not.

```
#check service is running or not

$ServiceName = 'AppIDSvc'
$arrService = Get-Service -Name $ServiceName

while ($arrService.Status -ne 'Running')
{

    Start-Service $ServiceName
    write-host $arrService.status
    write-host 'Service starting'
    Start-Sleep -seconds 15
    $arrService.Refresh()
    if ($arrService.Status -eq 'Running')
    {
        Write-Host 'Service is now Running'
    }

}
```

Comment: I have similar logic to start the service which will come after the installation of my .msi binary. I want to install my binary first.

Comment: @Ashwin,okay, normally when you try to run that msi, which exe is running ,because installation package all comes with .msi,need to know which one like PkgMgr.exe or wsua.exe or any other?

Comment: i'm trying to install 'sensu'